# Delete every users from a group

Tags: bash, users, group

I search **a clean way** to delete every users from the 'sudo' group. On several distributions the user created during the installation process has sudo rights, I don't want this. I search for an automated method working for (nearly) every situations.

Basically, I want to empty a group.

To remove every users : `GROUP=my_group; for u in $(getent group $GROUP | sed -e 's/^.*:.*:.*://' -e 's/,/ /g'); do echo gpasswd --delete $u $GROUP; done`
This command line works :
 1. if the group doesn't exist
 2. if the group is empty
 3. if the group contains one user
 4. if the group contains several users
So everything is okay. But is their something simplier ?

Another way is to delete the group, and recreate it. Ugly ?

Comment: How about just deleting the group and then recreating it?

Comment: Either make sure you have the root password set, or better leave at least one user in the sudo group that can keep this privilege. Also make sure you have an extra open root shell when experimenting with this, so you can always revert your changes.

Comment: Consider updating `/etc/login.defs` with your preferred defaults for future new users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you shouldn't delete a group because some files may belong to that group but it may be sufficient for your specific sudo usecase.

A more general usecase is to use [`gpasswd (1)`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=gpasswd&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en) at it allows you to set the members of a specific group, so it should be enough to run:

```
gpasswd sudo -M ''
```

To only run this if the group sudo exists you can combine it with a getent call, i.e.:

```
getent group sudo && gpasswd sudo -M ''
```

Comment: Does this cover cases where sudo is a primary group for some users?

Comment: @Nils no as `gpasswd` is used to manage `/etc/group` but the primary group is specified in `/etc/passwd`

Answer (score 2):

There's another way using command `/usr/sbin/groupmems` ("administer members of a user's primary group") on systems that have this command:

```
groupmems --purge --group <group_to_clean>
```

or using short options:

```
groupmems -p -g <group_to_clean>
```

All members will be removed from the group.

Tested in CentOS and Fedora.